# Create CoRD Compatible RDP file

Tags: rdp

I'm trying to generate a Remote Desktop RDP file that is compatible with CoRD verion 5701 or Microsoft Remote Desktop Version 8 for mac. I don't care if the password can't be saved in the file. I realize that has separate challenges.

My question is, has anyone successfully generated an RDP file, copied it into CoRD's servers directory, and successfully opened the file?

Here is the format I'm generating:

```
 connect to console:i:1
 redirectdrives:i:0
 redirectprinters:i:0
 disable wallpaper:i:1
 disable full window drag:i:1
 disable menu anims:i:1
 disable themes:i:0
 disable font smoothing:i:0
 audiomode:i:2
 desktopwidth:i:1680
 desktopheight:i:1050
 session bpp:i:16
 cord save password:i:0
 cord fullscreen:i:0
 cord row index:i:11
 cord hotkey:i:-1
 cord displayMode:i:0
 full address:s:1.2.3.4:10021
 username:s:myuser
 domain:s:mydomain
 cord label:s:myVm
```

When I open CoRD, it deletes all the values in the file. Alternatively if anyone has successfully done this for Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac, I'm interested to hear that as well. With MS desktop, I am able to import my RDP file (of course I omit the cord specific fields) but the name of the connection defaults to the "full address" field. I don't see a way to set a connection label in the RDP file like you can with the "cord label" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the format I was generating was correct. What was less obvious was that CoRD expects WINDOWS CRLF's at the end of each line!

I was generating these RDP files in groovy on a mac, and so I had to ensure that I was printing \r\n at the end of each line.